# What operations are performed when a class type is assigned to a de-referenced pointer of that class, in a single statement?

Tags: c++

Example:

Say we have a Node class with all those copy ctor, assignment operator, and default ctor overloaded.

Now, what constructors or operators will be called in which sequence when we have the following assignment:

```
Node myNode = *(new Node());
```

Comment: Use a debugger or `cout` statements to find out. Your code will leak memory like a sieve however. Assignment is out of discussion here BTW, it's the copy constructor being called.

Comment: Why is the copy ctor used instead of assignment operator?

Comment: Because initialization is handled differently than assignment.

Comment: When a object variable is declared and assigned in the same statement, copy construction is performed. IOW, `Node myNode = *(new Node());` is effectivelyy just convenient shorthand for calling the copy constructor like `Node myNode(*(new Node()));`

Comment: Okay, now, if you have a code like that is there any way to delete that memory through myNode? Or do we need to keep the original pointer?

Comment: No. Since you are using the object returned by `new` before you `delete` it, you need a separate variable to hold the object pointer so it can be passed from `new` to `delete`.

Comment: `Node myNode = *(new Node());` should simply be just `Node myNode;`. No need for Java-like syntax here.

Comment: Okay, so looks like copy ctor is used in a statement that is both initialization and declaration. And if it was already declared elsewhere, it will use assignment operator. Is that a correct behavior?

Comment: @RemyLebeau there are different rules for those two situations (the first is called *copy-initialization*, the second is *direct-initialization*

Comment: @user3330840 _"Is that a correct behavior?"_ Just don't use `new` and dereference a temporary result.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  How's new Node() a temporary result tho... if it was allocated in the heap? it's not anymore. So it's legit to dereference it. and to delete it like Node &mynode later. Not saying it's a smart thing to do tho.

Comment: @José It's temporary regarding the **reference** is lost immediately after the allocation and construction, that's what I meant to point out. _"and to delete it like Node &mynode later"_ Nope, that's blatantly wrong, it was dereferenced and copied.

Comment: And who says it was allocated on the heap, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Node`'a default constructor is called to construct an anonymous `Node` object.
2. `Node`'s copy constructor is called to copy-initialize `myNode`.
3. You leak one `Node` worth of memory, because the pointer returned by `new` goes out of scope as soon as the statement ends.  You can therefore never `delete` the `Node` you `new`ed.

`Node::operator=` is not invoked, because you are performing copy-initialization, which uses the copy constructor.  Something like:

```
Node myNode;
myNode = Node();
```

Would call `Node::operator=` instead of the copy constructor, since you're assigning to `myNode` after it has been constructed.

Answer (score 4):

`new Node()` - creates a new dynamically-allocated `Node` object. Yields a pointer to the new `Node`.

`*` - given a pointer, yields the thing it points to (as an lvalue).

`Node myNode =` - creates a new `Node` which is a local variable, and passes whatever's on the right side of the `=` to its constructor.

The overall effect: create a new local variable `Node`, create a dynamically-allocated `Node`, and copy the dynamic one to the local one. Additionally, you have no way to ever destroy the dynamic one, so this will cause a memory leak.